# Retaining Feature class Information Using Construct Polygons Modify Feature in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, polygon-creation, polyline-creation, modify-features

I have a polyline feature I need to turn into polygons but I don't have the license which would allow me to use the feature to polygon tool. The workaround as suggested on the [Construct Polygons From Features](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/editing/construct-polygons-from-features.htm) help page is to use the construct polygons modify feature. The problem is that the fields information doesn't carry over. I've tried using a spatial join to get this information from the polyline to the polygon in various ways but nothing turned out quite right and I'm at a loss if this would even be the correct thing to do.

How can I get this information from my polyline feature to the newly created polygon feature?

*Edit with Whitebox Tools Lines to Polygons*
The tool only partly worked. See the screenshot below which outlines sections that broke during the polygon creation process.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you have a polyline featureclass with polylines that enclose you could try and use the [LinesToPolygons](https://jblindsay.github.io/wbt_book/available_tools/data_tools.html#LinesToPolygons) in whitebox tools? I've not tried it but this may be an alternative if you don't have the correct license level.

A couple of caveats are:

- Your input data must be a shapefile
- I've used some of the tools in ArcMap and there is a user friendly implementation of it as a python toolbox which can be downloaded from github [here](https://github.com/giswqs/WhiteboxTools-ArcGIS)

Comment: Whitebox tools for Lines to Polygons only kind of worked. See the edited initial description outlining this attempt with screenshot.

Comment: One additional line of inquiry is that perhaps my polylines were not connected, however, one of the methods to test for this I have seen in several sources was to do the construct polygons from features step described initially and there are no errors at that stage which leads me to believe these lines are indeed closed. This leads me to believe the whitebox tool is just going bonkers somewhere...

Comment: @Therow I would strongly encourage you to provide feedback to the developer, they will appreciate it, you can leave an issue [here](https://github.com/jblindsay/whitebox-tools/issues). It's rare for developers to be able to cover every known scenario and your data may be throwing up something that has uncovered a weakness in the tool. Any feedback is helpful, and WBT is free after all! :)